# At what stage does a pipeline use the framebuffer?

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to understand when a pipeline starts to use framebuffer attachments in Vulkan. According to the specification, for the graphics primitive shading pipeline, the following stages occur in this order:

```
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_DRAW_INDIRECT_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_CONTROL_SHADER_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_EVALUATION_SHADER_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BIT_EXT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_SHADING_RATE_IMAGE_BIT_NV
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT
```

As far as I know, when only one attachment is used (no multi-sampling, just a single colour attachment), the pipe line should start writing to the framebuffer attachment at the rasterisation stage (so around somewhere before `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`). However, according to the specification, this should not happen until `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` stage. So, do pipelines use some intermediate, self-allocated memory to do all the fragment operations, and start writing to a swapchain image only at the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` stage? I only started working with Vulkan about two weeks ago, and I feel like there is some serious flaw in my reasoning, so it would be great if someone could point it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipeline starts to use the color attachment in first subpass that uses it in `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, depth and\or stencil in `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`. This is given by Load Operation (`loadOp`).

> [...] start writing to the framebuffer attachment at the rasterisation stage (so around somewhere before `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`)

Depth would be tested and potentially written there. Color cannot be written there; you do not even know what values to write without fragment shader.

But AIS, first use in render pass instance is the Load Operation, not the actual depth tests and writes.

> So, do pipelines use some intermediate, self-allocated memory to do all the fragment operations, and start writing to a swapchain image only at the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` stage?

Pipelines (as in the API abstraction) no; it does not care how the driver does it. As for drivers they might do any number of things. Render Pass is mostly necessitated by tile-based architectures. There, Load Operation is something that actually matches the HW. The attachment may be literally loaded from general purpose memory to "on-chip memory" for processing of the given tile.

Other architectures may operate under the "as-if" principle. Note it is not valid to use attachment in non-attachment uses between Load and Store Op. Also note that the only two available Store operations are allowed to write to the attachment. So, if the driver operates directly on memory of the attachment, it would still be a conformant Vulkan implementation.

> following stages occur in this order

I also get the notion that you think this means more than it means.

This is "logical order". This relates to Primitive Order and Rasterization Order. Yes, for a given pixel `(x, y)` they would happen in order. But that does **not** mean the driver has to wait on all the pixels before it writes them to memory. So no, with that in mind, you would not necessarily need "some intermediate, self-allocated memory".

Comment: So, as far as I understand, it is up to the driver how to handle everything? It may use the colour attachment at rendering time, but it may also use it only to output the final image?

Comment: Well, not "everything"; only the implementation details. I feel you still miss the point conceptually. It will use the color attachment at the time when the first tile is finished and ready for Store Operation, or on conventional architectures when the first primitive is finished. And it will continue to use it until all tiles\primitives reach the color writes stage.

Comment: Either way the underlying attachment will likely be used\streamed out to continually during execution if `STORE_OP_STORE`. The stage order is dependent on primitives, **not** global. For a given pixel `(x,y,layer,sample)` the attachment would be written at the last pipeline stage. But that may mean some other primitive may not have even executed the first pipeline stage. See: Primitive Order, and Rasterization Order.